# Flux Cored MIG on unknown steels, what is this stuff?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

Welding on some unknown Steel, I made the weld, and this stuff formed. It looks like a fast shutter speed shot of smoke or something for me but it's a solid material that has formed. It almost seems like millions of little Fibers at all flowed along with the hot air and gases coming off the weld. Has anyone seen this stuff before and does anyone have an idea what it is?

Comment: A guess would be products of combustion from the gases and any flux or dirt on the workpiece...

Comment: It is not steel. Apparently some kind of composite .It would be good for magic tricks.

Comment: I feel like its an alloying element, or something from some remaining powder coat or paint or whatever surface treatment is had on it. But I wire wheeled it after paint stripping, could been some I missed...